# I am getting error that #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h> not found in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, cocoapods, twitterkit

I installed these pod files.

`pod 'TwitterKit'`

`pod 'TwitterCore'`

When I try to import file i. e **#import** **< TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h >** it is showing  not found error.

Why it is comming any idea ? anything going wrong or anything is pending to add ?

Comment: If using Swift you will need to add it to your Objective-C bridging header.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Import it as a module using `@import TwitterKit`.

Comment: It is working. I was following twitter documentation, there they mentioned like that.So I was stucked from last 2 days, now got the solution. Thanks @Nikos

Comment: :-) Please upvote and accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 16):

Since version 3.3.0 TwitterKit has a new home on github, the [installation page](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation) states that you need to import like this:

`#import <TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Before import tries to clean and build your project or restart Xcode, then import Twitter.